# JavaScript coin flip animation with custom image on either side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm currently developing a site in which 2 users go head to head in a "coin flip", a Materialize CSS modal pops up on each users screen (the winner has already been defined), I then want there to be a coin flip animation.

I'm going to use this coin flip animation: https://www.html5andbeyond.com/coin-flip-application-html-css-and-jquery/

My question is how can I set the coin flip to land on a specific winner before the animation, also, how can I change it so there's a custom image on each side?

Thanks,

James

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder There's no "relevant code", this question is on the functionality and execution of displaying a coin flip animation with a pre-defined coin side

Comment: @iJamesPHP Not certain what Question is ?

Comment: @guest271314 ok let me edit the question to something more easy

Comment: @iJamesPHP What have you tried ? Can you include `html`, `css` attempts to resolve issues at Question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the changes to make in the css of that Codepen to place an image on either side of the coin. Click 'Edit on Codepen' on  https://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/pJZpee

```
#coin .front {
    transform: translateZ(1px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200/E8117F/000000');
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
}

    #coin .back {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200/000000/E8117F');
     background-size: cover;
     display: block;
}
```

To make the coin fall on a specific side do the following on that same codepen you gave us.

Heads:
Change the 'var spinArray' line to

```
var spinArray = ['animation1080'];
```

Tails:
Change the 'var spinArray' line to

```
var spinArray = ['animation900'];
```

I can't take it any further without having access to your code. That should be enough to figure it out though.

Hope this helps.

Best,

Tim

Comment: Very helpful Tim, the only issue now is a slight "lag" on each spin, I think it's reloading the images constantly, how can I fix that?

Comment: I don't have any "lag" on my end. What browser are you using? If 
I have time later I'll check it out. Meanwhile, may In ask that you accept the answer if it accurately answers your original question, "My question is how can I set the coin flip to land on a specific winner before the animation, also, how can I change it so there's a custom image on each side?".

Comment: Sorry I meant to accept it but am fairly new to SO, so I only upvoted, I can probably find my way for the rest, thankyou very much